# 正規表現で行をまたぐ文書の編集は可能でしょうか？

Tags: 正規表現

正規表現はOnigmo、Boost.Regex、秀丸のどれかです。

たとえば以下の事例です。

これより上はすべていらないので全行削除

ここからが体験記です
○○○○という記事
○○○○という記事

ここまでが体験記です
これより下はすべていらないので全行削除

"ここからが体験記です"　これより上の行にある前置きの文章行はすべていらないの一括削除するという方法です。
この中間の文章だけを残して
"ここまでが体験記です"　これより下の行はすべて一括で削除するという正規表現です。

これを正規表現以外でも可能でしたらお願いいたします｡
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 既に解決済みですが、Boost.Regex を使う場合は[こちら](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ki1ELt0rxlmSgXHd)

Comment: 勉強になります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正規表現１回で置換する方法ではありませんが、次の手順でお望みのことができると思いす。

１）改行コードをテキストに現れないであろう文字(たとえば制御コード0x03)に置換し、全テキストを１行にします
２）正規表現(たとえば「.*ここからが体験記です」)にマッチするものを削除する
３）１）で改行コードを置換した文字を改行コードに置換する

以上は秀丸で確認しました。

Comment: 解決できました。ありがとうございます。